# Web Api what are the default model binders and where do i reference them

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have just started with Web Api and after completing a few tutorials and **small** test projects I felt confident enough to build a "real world" application.

At the point when I first created the solution I removed everything that I believed was not necessary. During that exercise I must have removed some binder because when I POST/PUT a complex object it is always null.

In short my question is **In web api what are the default model binders and where do i reference them?** Below I have covered what I am trying to do and what I have tried to resolve this issue in more detail.

**What i'm trying to do**
I have two solutions running, and in each solution I have the same classes. I am trying to pass a complex object from solution A to solution B. When I hit the break-point in solution B the passed value is always null (solution B is my "real world" project which has the issues).

**What I have tried**
After reading several stackoverflow threads and [how web api does binding](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jmstall/2012/04/16/how-webapi-does-parameter-binding/) I tried to call an action in the same solution and pass the same object, IT WORKED! for example

- Pass the object from solutionA.method1 to solutionA.controller1.action1 WORKS
- Pass the object from solutionB.method1 to solutionB.controller1.action1 FAILS (500 - internal server error)

I have compared the solutions to try and work out what I've removed that could cause this issue, but without any success. I could create a new solution to resolve the isssue but I don't feel I will learn anything from taking that route. I would be really grateful if anyone could point me in the right direction so I can resolve this and learn a liitle more about web api.

**Code that works but in the same solution**

SOLUTION A

```
public const string uri = "http://localhost:49611/api/Values";

public async Task<string> PutAValue()
{
    var propertyForm = new AddUpdatePropertyForm();
    var network = new Network { NetworkID = 123456 };
    var branch = new Branch { BranchID = 1, Channel = Channel.Sales, Overseas = false };
    var property = new Property { AgentRef = "123", Published = true, PropertyType = PropertyType.SemiDetachedBungalow, Status = TransactionStatus.Available };
    propertyForm.Network = network;
    propertyForm.Branch = branch;
    propertyForm.Property = property;

    using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var responce = await httpClient.PutAsJsonAsync<AddUpdatePropertyForm>(uri, propertyForm);

        ...more stuff...
    }
}
```

SOLUTION A

```
public void Put([FromBody]AddUpdatePropertyForm form)
{
    ...Has all passed values but IN THE SAME SOLUTION...
}
```

**Code that doesn't work using solution a and solution b**

SOLUTION A

```
public const string uri = "http://localhost:58814/api/sample";

public async Task<string> PutAValue()
{
    var propertyForm = new AddUpdatePropertyForm();
    var network = new Network { NetworkID = 123456 };
    var branch = new Branch { BranchID = 1, Channel = Channel.Sales, Overseas = false };
    var property = new Property { AgentRef = "123", Published = true, PropertyType = PropertyType.SemiDetachedBungalow, Status = TransactionStatus.Available };
    propertyForm.Network = network;
    propertyForm.Branch = branch;
    propertyForm.Property = property;

    using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var responce = await httpClient.PutAsJsonAsync<AddUpdatePropertyForm>(uri, propertyForm);

        ...more stuff...
    }
}
```

SOLUTION B

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Put([FromBody]AddUpdatePropertyForm propertyForm)
{
    ...propertyForm ALWAYS null...
}
```

**Code that works using solution a and solution b** (but I want to receive the object NOT a string - as I am able to do when passing it within the same solution)

SOLUTION A

```
public const string uri = "http://localhost:58814/api/sample";

public async Task<string> PutAValue()
{
    var propertyForm = new AddUpdatePropertyForm();
    var network = new Network { NetworkID = 123456 };
    var branch = new Branch { BranchID = 1, Channel = Channel.Sales, Overseas = false };
    var property = new Property { AgentRef = "123", Published = true, PropertyType = PropertyType.SemiDetachedBungalow, Status = TransactionStatus.Available };
    propertyForm.Network = network;
    propertyForm.Branch = branch;
    propertyForm.Property = property;

    using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var content = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(propertyForm);
        var response = await httpClient.PutAsJsonAsync<string>(uri, content);

        ...more stuff...
    }
}
```

SOLUTION B

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Put([FromBody]string propertyForm)
{
    var content = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<AddUpdatePropertyForm>(propertyForm);
}
```

Comment: Is AddUpdatePropertyForm type reused across Solution A and Solution B?

Comment: Yes, the same classes are held in solution A and solution B

Comment: Can you post the AddOrUpdatePropeftyForm type ?